# Will it speed up the client-server communication If I added a separate router nearby?

Tags: wireless-networking, synergy

I'm using synergy connected to a wireless router that is quite far away. Signal is about 50~60% and there are some delays to keystroke and especially mouse-movement.

My current work-around is to have the mouse hover over to the Client side and then actually use the mouse hooked up to Client.

I still would prefer to use the Server-side Mouse since I am using Thinkpad and trackpoint is quite useful.

I was thinking of purchasing a wifi-router/switch to put on my desktop, and connect to the that router/switch. I would assume that the server-client connection is made within that router and it will significant speed up the connection.

Am I right thinking this way or has anyone tried to improve server-client connection in some other way (LAN is not an available option)?

Thanks,

Comment: if you really can't get a wired switch, then a WiFi Range extender installed near your desk is probably your best bet.

Comment: I think an AP Client (ie WIFI to Ethernet) is a better option as it does not reduce the available WIFI bandwidth like a range extender does.

Comment: Do "range extenders" actually do that? WiFi-WiFi _repeaters_ definitely would, but I've mainly seen the term 'range extender' applied to Eth-WiFi APs only, which wouldn't have such a problem... Anyway, either is better than a "router". You don't really want two routers, each doing NAT, stacked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend a WiFi extender in your situation, Synergy doesn't always perform smoothly over wireless but if you have no way of going ahead with a wired solution extending the range of your wireless is the best idea.